# Firefox throw a n error drawArraysInstanced: but attribs only supply 0, when I make drawArrays while Chrome is good

Tags: webgl

I've replaced gl.bufferData with non typed javascript arrays with typed Float32Arrays and now when I make drawArrays call nothing happen in FF but this

> Error: WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: Vertex fetch requires 30000,
>   but attribs only supply 0.

Comment: post a repo in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Otherwise my only guess is your code is using the wrong attribute locations and the assigned attributes locations are different on chrome than firefox.

Comment: Yep...my fault. Child mistake. I missed filling one of my arrays. Thank you I thought FF was wrong, but seems to be that Chrome webgl engine ignores somehow empty arrays inside!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zemledelec's answer helped me but to anyone still struggling with this I can offer a rough explanation.

The problem was my call to `gl.drawArrays` expected more vertex data than it received. The vertex data was missing because my call to `gl.bufferData` was failing. I fixed the problem by providing `gl.bufferData` with a Float32Array object instead of the typical javascript array object.

replaced...

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verts, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

with...

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

So if you are receiving this error, make sure you are providing **all** the vertex data you are attempting to draw.

Answer (score 1):

Done! Forget fill typed array with data.